# How to provide background color to half of two div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.bg {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-rainbow-texture-1491566442.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

How to add background to half of two div? (to bottom half of first div and upper half of second one).
changing height is changing height of whole div.

[image: Like the brown bg in this page]

Like the brown background in the picture. How to add common background in middle of two separate div?

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you meant. Explain a little more clearly what you want

Comment: @meysamasadi sorry, updated with little more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) for background.

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ddd 50%, #9A8D6D 50%); /* Go towards the bottom, Cover #ddd for 50%, Cover #9a8d60 for the other half */
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-rainbow-texture-1491566442.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want margin between the background, you can make use of color stops inside:

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ddd 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #9A8D6D 50%); /* Go towards the bottom, Cover #ddd for 5%, Cover transparent from 25 - 50%, cover #9A8D6D for the other half */
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-rainbow-texture-1491566442.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. That helped. Is there any way to give margins and padding to background?

Comment: For full background, you can target the div itself. For each background, you can make use of color stops as updated.